# Creating a column for a View from two different tables (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, left-join

I have three tables A, B and C in a SQL Server, **B** and **C** share the same foreign key (`AgencyID`) from **A**, and they also share one same column name: `AgencyName`

Table **A**: `AgencyID`, `AgencyDate`,

Table **B**: `AgencyID`, `AgencyNumber`, **AgencyName**

Table **C**: `AgencyID`, `AgencyInvoiceNumber`, **AgencyName**

To help you understand the relationship, basically these 3 tables are generated with **Entity Framework**, where `B` and `C` each extends `A`.

Now I am trying to create one View from these three tables in the following way:

```
CREATE VIEW [rdo].[Agencies] AS
SELECT
    A_1.AgencyID, A_1.AgencyDate,
    dbo.B.AgencyNumber, dbo.B.AgencyName,
    dbo.C.AgencyInvoiceNumber, dbo.C.AgencyName
FROM dbo.A AS A_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.B ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.B.AgencyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.C ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.C.AgencyID
```

Now, apparently the script errors about `AgencyName` that column name in a view should be unique :( How would I go about this so that both `AgencyName` values from B and C are merged into one view?

Note: I know the example isn't perfect as one could just move the column to table A, but it's just a simplified example, in reality I really cannot simply move the column :(

---

Reason for having to have duplicated columns in B and C:

Here's the relationships:

```
            A 
           / \
          A1  A2
         /      \
        B        C
```

A1 and A2 extends A, B and C extends A1 and A2 respectively. `AgencyName` is an unique attribute that only B and C has. I know a refactoring could be done here to try to get rid of this weird hierarchy, but this legacy project has already grown too big and I cannot afford the cost atm.

Comment: I do not understand your business, but I found that [AgencyID] is the same. why do not you use [INNER JOIN]

Comment: if you are using entity framwork 6, then you do not need join bro.... u can directly access thoe 2 tables

Comment: You better not to include your Agency name twice as it is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using COALESCE to pick the first non null AgencyName:

```
CREATE VIEW [rdo].[Agencies] AS
SELECT
    A_1.AgencyID, A_1.AgencyDate,
    dbo.B.AgencyNumber, 
    COALESCE(dbo.B.AgencyName, dbo.C.AgencyName) As AgencyName,
    dbo.C.AgencyInvoiceNumber 
FROM dbo.A AS A_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.B ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.B.AgencyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.C ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.C.AgencyID
```

You may face the issue where AgencyName is different in B & C in which case you will need a set of rules to follow.
My recommendation is to only have AgencyName in one of the tables (Table A?) otherwise you face potential update discrepancies.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give different names to those columns in the view whose name are same in your tables like below

```
CREATE VIEW [rdo].[Agencies] AS
SELECT
    A_1.AgencyID, A_1.AgencyDate,
    dbo.B.AgencyNumber, dbo.B.AgencyName AS AgencyName_B,
    dbo.C.AgencyInvoiceNumber, dbo.C.AgencyName AS AgencyName_C
FROM dbo.A AS A_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.B ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.B.AgencyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.C ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.C.AgencyID
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without giving them two different names?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW [rdo].[Agencies] AS
SELECT
    A_1.AgencyID, A_1.AgencyDate,
    dbo.B.AgencyNumber, dbo.B.AgencyName as AgencyNameB,
    dbo.C.AgencyInvoiceNumber, dbo.C.AgencyName as AgencyNameC,
FROM dbo.A AS A_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.B ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.B.AgencyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.C ON A_1.AgencyID = dbo.C.AgencyID
```

give `alice name`  to `AgencyName` column. 
In your case the table `dbo.table.AgencyName` will have a column called 'AgencyName' for Tables `B` and `C` . That is the problem. Give alicename to any one of the column or both.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without giving them two different names?

Comment: @JoelMin, You need to have two columns AgencyName. ? or merge the AgencyName  from B and C and have only one AgencyName  column ?

Comment: I need to merge the AgencyName from B and C and have only one AgencyName :)